# Edit the value of a JComboBox entry without triggering a selection change

Tags: java, swing

I have a small app with a GUI created using the `Swing` libraries.

Every time I update the entry of a combobox, the function `actionPerformed`( which triggers normally when the user chooses another value of the combo box) is getting triggered. The code which updates the entry is this one:

```
comboBox.setEditable(true);
comboBox.setSelectedItem("some text");
comboBox.setEditable(false);
```

Is there another method to update the value of the currently selected entry on the combo box without triggering the function which handles the selection change?

Comment: Yes: you can test a flag in your `actionPerformed` method

Comment: @MadProgrammer not an exact duplicate since I just want to edit the selection of the `ComboBox`, but I'm fine with that anyway.

Comment: @MauricePerry I already worked with flags, but it's getting more complex if I want to add other features. I just thought there is some method I missed in the documentation

Comment: @JohnDoe It's conceptual the same thing - as `setSelectedItem` is  triggered when the user selects the item